# Gradient fill in PDF figure turns out solid filled in compiled document

Tags: pdf, gradient

**UPDATE**:
It turns out it was a compatibility issue with the PDF viewers.
Apple Preview, Adobe Acrobat Professional 8 and Firefox display the compiled document wrongly. Under TeXWork and Adobe Reader 11, Google Chrome it is displayed as intended.

I have a pdf file included as a figure in my document. 
It has a shape with a gradient fill. I'am afraid, in the compiled (pdflatex) document the shape is filled with a solid colour.

Since there is no compile error or warning indicating the gradient fill, I would like to know where to start correcting this misbehaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{filename}
\caption{figure caption}
\label{fig:figurelable}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[Link to pdf file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2119405/stubbscal.pdf)

[Link to compiled pdf file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2119405/mwe.pdf)

I included screenshots to illustrate the situation.

[image: Image of correct figure]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to see the PDF with the gradient fill?

Comment: File works for me, displaying correctly in TeXworks build-in PDF viewer. However, it does show as a solid colour in Firefox's HTML5 viewer. Which viewer(s) are you using?

Comment: I was using apple preview. It displays the original included pdf correctly.  I will attach the compiled pdf as well.

Comment: @user24537 Preview shows your PDF fine, but misses out the colour entirely if I include it in a PDF. However, Adobe Reader on Mac is fine with both. I suggest a viewer issue.

Comment: I see it correctly with Skim, Preview, Adobe Reader and also the internal previewer of TeXworks.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Prof 8 does not show the beam at all. But it is good to have your confirmation. Btw: Is there a FAQ comparing/recommending certain pdf viewers?

Comment: @user24537 The `stubbs.pdf` file is PDF level 1.5; Adobe Acrobat 8 should be able to interpret it. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using texlive2011

Comment: I see it correctly with evince, okular and Acrobat Reader 9 in Linux.

Comment: Any update on this? I have the same problem. I want to be sure other people using Preview etc. can see my image properly. Where in the pdflatex pipeline is the transparency lost?